# How to create VC++ header and source file templates in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

How i can create such templates. And also i want to have new folder for all my templates in New File  -> Installed Templates.

I have found how to create templates for C# projects only.

EDIT:
To clarify, i need allow user to create source and header files prefilled with some data.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio project templates are different for C++ and are called wizards instead.

You can see how to create a C++ wizard [by checking this MSDN link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/96xz4cw2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If you just want to create custom *Item Templates*, for example for header files or code files, [take a look at MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or, more specifically, [MSDN here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247113%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: sorry, i meant templates only for source and header files

Comment: Don't know how, but it create C# template though i followed all instruction, but anyway +1